# The verb "offer" followed by that

Tags: verbs

In your variety of English, can "offer" be followed by a clause beginning with the word "that"?

> I offered that he stay home.

or should it be

> I offered that he stayed/would stay home.

Comment: Are you offering 'him' the opportunity to stay at home rather than go somewhere disagreeable, or offering someone else the opportunity to have 'him' there to keep them company?

Answer (score 1):

I speak AmE and can think of two meanings that would work here.

First, you might mean something like the following:

> My wife suggested that our son go to school today, but I offered that he stay home.

The dependent clauses use what is often called the present subjunctive; therefore, their predicates should be headed by verbs in the bare infinitive form ("go" and "stay"). However, it is a bit unusual to use the present subjunctive after the verb "offer"; verbs such as "suggest", "insist", "demand", "recommend", and "request" are more commonly used with the present subjunctive. ([See here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv201.shtml), for example.) Many people will probably find this sentence non-idiomatic for that reason.

On the other hand, you might mean something like the following:

> We were trying to figure out what he had done on Monday afternoon. My wife suggested that he had gone out, but I offered that he had stayed home.

In this case, the speaker offered a possible answer to the question that they were pondering. This is correct, but I used the past perfect ("had stayed") because that seemed to make more sense with the sequence of events.

I have not addressed "would stay" because that might involve a lengthy discussion, since there are several meanings of "would". If you clarify what you mean, then I'd be happy to address whether "would stay" might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of [conditional statement](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) and, in general, the simple past is accompanied by the present conditional or present continuous conditional. So the best answer is:

> I offered that he would stay home.

That said, you could probably get away with the first version in spoken English, and it wouldn't be all that unusual.